# MapKit - tracing an object's movement in real time

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpolyline, cllocationcoordinate2d

I can map a line like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[5];

pointsToUse[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.103100,-108.353706);
pointsToUse[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.103100,-108.354706);
pointsToUse[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.103100,-108.355706);
pointsToUse[3] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.103100,-108.356706);
pointsToUse[4] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(44.103100,-108.357706);

MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:5];
[self.mapView addOverlay:myPolyline];
```

But my question is how to keep adding to the line in real time. Say I get array which contains a new set of coordintates (this means the object that I'm mapping has moved). I need to keep tracing the object's progress on the map. Obviously I can do this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[2];
pointsToUse[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.103100,-118.357706);
pointsToUse[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(34.105100,-118.357706);
MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:2];
[self.mapView addOverlay:myPolyline];
```

So, just adding more MKPolylines on the map. Is this the best way to do this? Or is there some way to just use one MKPolyline and have it update?

Comment: I think it would be better to keep one polyline and just redraw it. I can't check docs atm for mutability but yeah just add the new point to the array and create the line again.

Comment: You might take a look at Apple's [Breadcrumb](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html) example to see if it does what you're looking for.

Comment: I looked at Breadcrumb. It seems only useful for tracking the user's changes in location. I'm getting data in the form of a set of coordinates from a another user.

Comment: @soleil One `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is as good as another, yeah? It's the drawing part that should interest you, I'd think. In `BreadcrumbViewController`, look at `- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation`. You'd want to adapt the code there to work with whatever method you're using to handle coordinate updates. For `oldLocation.coordinate`, store your last plotted coordinate. For `newLocation.coordinate`, use whatever your new coordinate is. `CrumbPathView` will handle the drawing for you.

Comment: @PeterHeide I implemented it like you said, and it does work. However, I was setting the visible map rect via `[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:self.polyline.boundingMapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50) animated:YES];` and now that I'm using the CrumbPathView I can't figure out how to get a bounding rect for the map.